# fslview cannot be installed (in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to use fsl, fslview, freesurfer in order to process neuroimaging data, but I have encountered unsolvable problem.

I use 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows', my computer is Windows 10 Pro (64Bit), I have installed and run Xming, and I have successfully installed fsl using the commands below. I followed instructions on http://www.nemotos.net/?p=1481.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
wget -O- http://neuro.debian.net/lists/trusty.us-nh.full | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neurodebian.sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:800xA5D32F012649A5A9
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fsl
```

However, when I enter:

```
sudo apt-get install fslview
```

I get the error message as below.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed.
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation 
or if you are using the unstable distribution 
that some required packages have not yet been created 
or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
fslview : Depends: libvtk5.8 but it is not installable
          Depends: libvtk5.8-qt4 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried to install libvtk5.8 and libvtk5.8-qt4, but it doesn't work. Iibvtk is installed in version 6.2. Does it have to do with conflicts or mix of various ubuntus? I've also installed oracle VM virtualbox and created an instance of Ubuntu, in which I've installed fslview. I heard that someone else have successfully installed fslview as well as fsl without any error by installing in a fresh trusty docker.

Comment: Check your version of "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" (`cat /etc/lsb-release`) - most likely it is 16.04

Comment: I've checked it.  Below are the results.  `DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu`  `DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04`  `DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial`   `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"`

Comment: So you will need to modify the instructions - replacing "trusty" by "xenial" as appropriate

Comment: Thank you very much! Now fslview as well as fsl is working! Oh, the code in the 4th line should be changed as: `sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 0xA5D32F012649A5A9`

Comment: I get the warning messages below when I tried to install fsl and fslview. Is it safe to ignore them? `perl: warning: Setting locale failed.`
`perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:`
`        LANGUAGE = (unset),`
`        LC_ALL = (unset),`
`        LANG = "en_us_8859_1"`
`    are supported and installed on your system.`
`perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").`
`locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory`
`locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory`

Comment: `locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory`

Comment: `Xming` isn't the only kid in town. You could try [vcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) which some say is more current.

Comment: The `locale` refers to the configuration for the language, date- and money-formats used by you. -- You can [configure the `locale`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499794/how-to-fix-a-locale-setting-warning-from-perl) to avoid the warning: (1) You can modify the `/etc/locale.gen`  file and run `sudo locale-gen` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`; and/or (2) set the `LANGUAGE`, `LANG`, `LC_ALL` and `LC_TYPE` environment variables.